# Startin Owin manually

Tags: signalr, startup, owin

For some reason I don't want to scan assemblies on startup (namely, I'm getting an InvalidProgramException because of an issue with the DotfuscatorAttribute). What I need is disable automatic app startup (I already know how to do it) and then call the startup method manually.

My question is, after I disable automatic startup via the config setting, how do I manually start it? I need it to get SignalR working.

Comment: There are 2 steps in general when a Startup.Configuration() is invoked. 1) scanning of assemblies with the OwinStartup attribute (2) Instantiation of startup object and calling Configuration method. If you would like to avoid step 1 then you can specify the fully qualified startup class name in the appSetting "owin:AppStartup" with something like "MyApplication.Startup, MyApplication". For more information you can refer to this : http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection

Comment: Thanks!!! can you make it an answer so that I could mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 steps in general when a Startup.Configuration() is invoked.

1. Scanning of assemblies with the OwinStartup attribute
2. Instantiation of startup object and invoking the Configuration method over it.

If you would like to avoid step 1 then you can specify the fully qualified startup class name in the appSetting "owin:AppStartup" with something like "MyApplication.Startup, MyApplication". For more information you can refer to [this](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection) article.